# How to get 10 rows for a single cursor fetch

Tags: postgresql

I have following code,I want to fetch 10 rows from cursor and then save them in an array,

Here, with this code, I just want to know how to get 10 (or some other value) rows from a single fetch.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_fetch_many(num INTEGER)
returns integer as $$
DECLARE
  my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT a,b,c FROM t_0038;
  my_array t_0038 ARRAY;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor;
  FETCH 10 FROM my_cursor INTO my_array; --ERROR here
  CLOSE my_cursor;
  foreach r in my_array
  loop
  raise notice 'r is %', r
  end loop;
  return 0;
    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I run the above code, it complains that `FETCH can't return multiple rows`

I would like to know how to fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: 1) See [plpgsql using cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING): *43.7.3.5. Returning Cursors*. Return the cursor from the function and then you can use the multiple row variants of the [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) command. 2) From the cursor link: *However, PL/pgSQL users do not normally need to worry about that, since FOR loops automatically use a cursor internally to avoid memory problems.*. So you can achieve what you are doing now with a `FOR` loop.